# How do I organize/store a "type" field for a comments table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

My application has about half a dozen different types of items that a user can comment on (articles, photos, videos, user profiles, blog posts, forum posts).

My plan right now is to have a single `comments` table in my database and then have `parent_id` and `type` fields in the table.

The `type` field would just be a `string` and the contents of it would be the name of it's parent table. So for an Article comments, the type would be `article`, for example.

Is that the best way to handle the `comments` table? Or is there some other, more efficient way to do that?

Comment: I'd create a separate comments table for each type of comments so that I could easily apply foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a polymorphic association would be the best way to achieve this - check out Ryan's [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association) on the subject (or the ASCIIcast at http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association). I think you'll end up with something like:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

end
```

Then each model you want users to be able to comment on will have the line:

```
has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
```

I also found [this post](http://wiki.github.com/hcatlin/make_resourceful/embedded-nested-polymorphic-comments) useful when setting up polymorphic comments. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a called a polymorphic association. Rails can handle that out of the box, see this episode:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association

Answer (score 0):

If a comment can't apply to multiple things (the same comment can't apply to both an article and a blog post, or two different articles) then why is it a base entity?

If you're committed to it, I'd have a comment table that looked like this:

```
COMMENT_ID
COMMENT_BODY
USER_ID
DATE
ARTICLE_ID references ARTICLE on delete cascade
BLOG_POST_ID references BLOG_POST on delete cascade
... etc
```

And then have constraint that says one and only one of the parents can apply.

An alternative is to have a COMMENT table for each base entity, so you'd have ARTICLE_COMMENTS, BLOG_POST_COMMENTS, and so forth.

Comment: Main reason is that it seems redundant. The would be practically identical as would the models associated with them.

Comment: @shpigford: identical column types does not equal redundant. If it feels that way, get over that feeling, it is leading you to unwarranted optimizations. If an article comment is functionally (semantically) different from a blog comment, then it deserves a separate table. Code lookup tables often look the same as well (name, value pairs), but there is no sense in chucking all codes (car type, engine type, paint type) in one table and then having to select car types from that table using an extra "where type = car type" condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking at plugins like [acts_as_commentable](http://rubygems.org/gems/acts_as_commentable), and looking at how they are implemented. Or just use the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is pretty good. It is simple and easy to implement. The only requirement would be that the data-types of the row identifiers would have to be the same as comment.parent_id so that your joins are consistent. I would actually define views on the comments table for each 'type'. For example, "create photo_comments as select * from comments where type = 'PHOTOS'". then you could join from PHOTOS to PHOTO_COMMENTS on PHOTOS.PHOTO_ID = PHOTO_COMMENTS.PARENT_ID, and so on.

You could also create a supertype say, widget, and each of your photo, blog_post etc. could be sub-types of widget. Then you could constrain your comments table to have an FK to the widget table. The 'type' column could then be moved to the widget table.